# A limit involving sinh

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to show that $$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\frac{\sinh(y\sqrt{2u}) + \sinh(x\sqrt{2u})}{\sinh((x + y)\sqrt{2u})} = -xy$$

The method I was trying resulted in pages and pages of messy computations, and I'm doubtful that this is the best way to go about it. Any ideas would be appreciated.

-- Thanks.

Comment: You could also use $$\sinh(p)+\sinh(q)=2\sinh(\frac{p+q}{2})\cosh(\frac{p-q}{2})$$ which will make life slightly easier and simplify using the double angle formula in denominator. The expression simplifies a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method Guide**

1. Expand the numerator and denominator into 2-term Taylor expansions.
2. Justify that the remaining terms of the numerator and denominator Taylor expansions can be discarded because the limit as $u \to 0$ kills them. So it suffices to use these expansions.
3. You should get
   $$ \frac{(x+y) + \frac{(x^3 + y^3)u}{3}}{(x+y) + \frac{(x+y)^3u}{3}}$$
   after you cancel and simplify a bit.
4. Notice that for general $f(u) = \frac{a+bu}{c+du}$, we get that $f'(u) = \frac{bc-ad}{(c+du)^2}$, so that as $u \to 0$, we get $\frac{bc-ad}{c^2}$
5. Plug in our situation above to get the result you want.

I carried this through, and I was a bit surprised to see if fall out so nicely at the end.

**Addendum on the Taylor Series of $\sinh x$**

Recall the Taylor series for $e^x$:
$$
e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots
$$
As $\sinh x = \dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2},$ we use the Taylor series for $e^x$ to see that
$$
\sinh x = x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \cdots
$$
This allows you to expand the numerator and denominator into Taylor polynomials.

Comment: Would you mind showing the taylor details. It's been a while since I've worked with these expansions. I'm also confused why you took the limit before you took the derivative.

Comment: I didn't take the limit before I took the derivative. I don't know what you mean there. But I'll add in something about Taylor series.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a hard time seeing why some terms disappear. You're right about the limit comment. I realized it was nonsense shortly after writing that.

Comment: I understood what the taylor series is. Sorry, I'm just not understanding how you arrived at your expression in (3). I don't understand why some terms die out, and which ones live.

Comment: I looked through it a bit more. I understand it clearly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=(x-y)/\sqrt2$ and $b=(x+y)/\sqrt2$.  Then
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{\sinh(x\sqrt{2u}) + \sinh(y\sqrt{2u})}{\sinh((x+y)\sqrt{2u})} \\
&= \lim_{u\to0}\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{\cosh(a\sqrt u)}{\cosh(b\sqrt u)} \\
&= \lim_{u\to0}\frac{a\Bigl(\overbrace{\frac{\sinh(a\sqrt u)}{2\sqrt u}}^{\to a/2}\Bigr)\cosh(b\sqrt u) - b\cosh(a\sqrt u)\Bigl(\overbrace{\frac{\sinh(b\sqrt u)}{2\sqrt u}}^{\to b/2}\Bigr)}{\cosh^2(b\sqrt u)} \\
&= \frac{a^2-b^2}{2} \\
&= -xy
\end{align*}